# Is there any way to know what happens when a Ubuntu Installation freeze?

Tags: system-installation, log

Is there any way to know what happens when a Ubuntu Installation from a pendrive is booting well but always get freeze after start GUI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is Ubuntu installed, on the pendrive or on the hard disk?

Comment: Sometimes you can boot, install ssh server, and ssh in after the freeze

Comment: It Isn't installed, I want to do this because when I try to test/install Ubuntu I can only move the mouse but nothing else, the gui looks freeze.
I want to know what happens, what is wrong with the laptop configuration.
Nothing reacts to the clicks of the mouse or keyboard.
Thank you.

Comment: 1) Which version of Ubuntu are you trying? 2) Does your PC meet the minimum system requirements for that version? https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar 3) If you redownload Ubuntu, run a checksum https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM to verify the downloaded file, and use another flashdrive to make a LiveUSB, does the problem persist?

Answer (score 0):

Review the logs generated by the [Ubiquity installer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity), such as
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/partman
/var/log/installer

Comment: How can I access these folders/files if the gui freezes right after loading?.
I can only move the mouse but nothing else.
Nothing reacts to the clicks of the mouse.
Thank you.